# AJAX login form not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a simple portal with a login page but I am stuck at AJAX problem as I am new to AJAX.

I have a file **login.php** in which there's a simple html form on clicking it will first check the sample credentials in a php file named **test.php**. But on entering a wrong credentials or no credentials I am using a **jgrowl notification** to popup in top right corner which shows two types of error first is **invalid credentials** and second is **error**. And on successful match it will redirect to index.php file.

Below is my code attached :

```
  <script>
$("#submit").click( function() {
        $.post( $("#login-validation").attr("action"),
        $("#login-validation :input").serializeArray(),
            function(data) {
                var x = data;
                if(x=="ok"){
                    $("#submit").html('Signing In ...');
                    setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ',4000);
                }
                else if(x=="error"){
                        $.jGrowl("error", {
                            sticky: false,
                            position: 'top-right',
                            theme: 'bg-blue-alt'
                        });
                } 
                else{
                    $.jGrowl( x , {
                          sticky: false,
                          position: 'top-right',
                          theme: 'bg-blue-alt'
                        });
                }               
            });
    $("#login-validation").submit( function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

login.php

```
    <form action="test.php" id="login-validation" class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-11 col-lg-3 center-margin" method="post">
        <h3 class="text-center pad25B font-white text-transform-upr font-size-23"><b>Employee Self Service Login</b></h3>
        <div id="login-form" class="content-box bg-default">
            <div class="content-box-wrapper pad20A">
                <img class="mrg25B center-margin radius-all-100 display-block" src="http://54.255.228.114/budget/assets/image-resources/indiannica.png" alt="" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon addon-inside bg-gray">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon addon-inside bg-gray">
                            <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
    </form>
```

test.php

```
   <?php
if($_POST['email']=="123"  && $_POST['password']=="123"){
    echo 'ok';
}else if($_POST['email']=="456"  && $_POST['password']=="456"){
    echo 'error';
}else if($_POST['email']=="789"  && $_POST['password']=="789"){
    echo 'invalid credentials';
}   
else{
    echo '404';
}?>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can trace the AJAX operation using the Network panel in your browser. What response code do you get? You should get 200. What is the body of the response?

Comment: You're missing to prevent the default behaviour of the submission of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated ajax code as well as test.php page

ajax code with datatype json

```
     $("#login-validation").submit( function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   dataVar = { email:$('input[name="email"]').val(), password:$('input[name="password"]').val() }

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
      data: dataVar,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
            var x = data;
            console.log(x);

            if(data.status=="success"){
                $("#submit").html('Signing In ...');
                setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ',4000);
            }
            else if(data.status=="error"){
                    $.jGrowl("error", {
                        sticky: false,
                        position: 'top-right',
                        theme: 'bg-blue-alt'
                    });
            } 
            else{
                $.jGrowl( x , {
                      sticky: false,
                      position: 'top-right',
                      theme: 'bg-blue-alt'
                    });
            }               
        }
});
});
```

test.php page which need to respond in json format only

```
<?php
if($_POST['email']=="123"  && $_POST['password']=="123"){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>"success"));
}else if($_POST['email']=="456"  && $_POST['password']=="456"){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>"error"));
}else if($_POST['email']=="789"  && $_POST['password']=="789"){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>"error"));
}   
else{
   echo json_encode(array('status'=>"404"));
}?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Script instead of your's

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $("#login-validation").submit( function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   dataVar = { email:$('input[name="email"]').val(), password:$('input[name="password"]').val() }

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
      data: dataVar,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
            var x = data;
            if(x=="ok"){
                $("#submit").html('Signing In ...');
                setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php"; ',4000);
            }
            else if(x=="error"){
                    $.jGrowl("error", {
                        sticky: false,
                        position: 'top-right',
                        theme: 'bg-blue-alt'
                    });
            } 
            else{
                $.jGrowl( x , {
                      sticky: false,
                      position: 'top-right',
                      theme: 'bg-blue-alt'
                    });
            }               
        }
});
});
```

Comment: Why to use this script instead of his ? Please, try to answer with explanations of what you changed/added/removed. These types of answers will not be helpful or understandable, an answer should be accompanied with explanations to benefit anyone who reads it. Kindly, try to inderstand my vision.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I tried your script but it is also showing the same things and not redirecting to the index.php page on succesful login. What i think is that there might be some gap between the php and this script. i.e the data we are sending from php our script cannot process it on the basis of if conditions.

Comment: It will work if you pass ajax post by json datatype. Currently it is passing post data in text format. Below I have added corrected answer for the bug.